# In postfix how do you read (or get) virtual users email?

Tags: postfix, email-server, email

This might seem like a dumb question, but... How do you read the mail for virtual users in postfix that have been created by `virtual_mailbox_domain`?

I've created a user named vuser that handles all virtual mailbox domain mail; I've even tested that my configuration works by sending a test email outside my network. But now I do not know how I'd check virtual users mail; and cant seem to find anything on Google about this.

Comment: Useful question, premature closure, 10 years later, I can understand what they are asking and it was exactly my question.  This is why ServerFault seems so hostile to users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something that understands the [maildir](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) format. Dovecot and Courier are 2 common software services that provide pop/imap access. However there are a lot of applications that can read  maildir (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maildir) for a good list).

Comment: Setting up a postfix virtual server is way beyond the scope of this site. There is an official guide that you can take a look at though, http://www.postfixvirtual.net/postfixconf.html

Comment: Postfix should be dropping all the mail for the virtual users in something like /var/spool/postfix/virtual/. You would then configure courier to look in that path for the mail. You would also need some sort of sasl authentication method for courier to authenticate the users against.